# How to make a transition on a button with delay in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift

How to make a transition on a button with delay (since my button has an animation) in iOS using swift?

Comment: Please share what you have attempted so far! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in the completion block of the animation

```
  UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: {
        //animate here
   }, completion: {
      // pushviewController OR perfrom Segue
  })
```

Or with dispatchAfter

```
 DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {


}
```

Comment: If the reason for the delay is to let an animation complete, the first option is much better since it ties the button action to the actual animation completion.

Comment: I agree , but also if time is static the second may be another way